# Display Django URL list in template

Tags: django, list, django-templates

So I have url like this:

```
example.com?category=Home&category=Test
```

I know that in the views I can read this list like this:

```
catlist = request.GET.getlist('category')
```

But how can I read this list in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your view you need to pass it to template which can use it as list.

For example

view.py

```
def myview(request):
    catlist = request.GET.getlist('category')
    #do something
    ....
    # pass catlist to template and may be some other variables
    ctx = { 'catlist': catlist}
    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', ctx,
                context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

mytemplate.html

```
{% for cat in catlist %}
    <p> {{cat}} </p>
 {%endfor%}
```